# Find line number of a value which matches upto 2 decimal in python numpy

Tags: python, numpy, decimal

I tried to find the line number of value which is 60 % of the maximum value in file.

```
if max_value=1
   v_60 = 0.6
```

My file looks like this,

```
2.140672782874617625e-02
9.785932721712538307e-02
1.651376146788990640e-01
2.140672782874617763e-01
2.568807339449541427e-01
2.996941896024464813e-01
3.363914373088685017e-01
3.639143730886849615e-01
3.975535168195718505e-01
4.097859327217125425e-01
4.250764525993884213e-01
4.525993883792048256e-01
4.678899082568807044e-01
4.740061162079510226e-01
4.954128440366972197e-01
5.076452599388379117e-01
5.259938837920489219e-01
5.351681957186543714e-01
5.443425076452599320e-01
5.626911314984709422e-01
5.871559633027523262e-01
6.055045871559633364e-01
6.055045871559633364e-01
6.116207951070335991e-01
6.238532110091742355e-01
8.715596330275228176e-01
8.623853211009173680e-01
8.715596330275228176e-01
8.807339449541283782e-01
8.837920489296635651e-01
8.807339449541283782e-01
8.899082568807338278e-01
8.868501529051986410e-01
9.663608562691131665e-01
9.816513761467889898e-01
9.755351681957186161e-01
9.724770642201834292e-01
9.785932721712538029e-01
9.877675840978593635e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00
```

Now I print the line number of the max value by

```
l=numpy.where(file == np.amax(file))
```

now how to find the line number which has 0.60 just comparing up to two decimal value only in python.

Comment: NONE of your numbers equals 0.60 when rounded to two decimals.  You have 0.61 twice, but not 0.60.

Comment: By the way, you can replace your where line with `l = np.argmax(file)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find the element closest to the 60% mark:

```
findit = data.max() * 0.6
print(np.argmin(np.abs((data-findit))))
```

Output:

```
21
```

Comment: @Indrani if the answer helped you, don't forget to vote/accept it

Comment: @mozway I need 15 reputations to cast a vote.

Comment: @Indrani but you can accept answers ;)

Comment: @mozway Thank you. I didn't know that. I accepted it.